# Facebook Comment is not shown on page

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, express, facebook-comments

i just added Facebook Comment Plugin on my website created with NodeJS and ReactJS and this is generated code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossOrigin="anonymous" 
src="https://connect.facebook.net/ka_GE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v3.3"></script>\

<div className="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:3000/recipe/:id/:name" 
data-width="" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

but it does not shows anything on the page, i use chrome and i disabled adblock on that page but nothing changed anyway, what is the reason of this and how can I fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use library `react-facebook`, in example :

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { FacebookProvider, Comments } from 'react-facebook';

export default class Example extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FacebookProvider appId="123456789">
        <Comments href="http://www.facebook.com" />
      </FacebookProvider>
    );
  }
}
```

You can find it at **npmjs** for more detail.

Comment: thank you! but there is no info about appId prop and href prop which you wrote down in example and is appId given or should i use "123456789"?

Comment: and should i change href?

Comment: Yes, you are also mode `href` attribute . You can search `react-facebook` on `npmjs` for more detail.